# What happens if multiple runcrons is executed

Tags: python, django, django-cron

I have multiple cron jobs written in Django and I'm using package `django-cron`. If I run the following command multiple times, what will happen?

```
python manage.py runcrons
```

I want if second runcrons sees that some cron job is executing by the first runcrons, simply ignore it and don't wait for the first one to be completed!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use django-cron, you'll be interested in the [locking backend](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/blob/master/docs/locking_backend.rst).

You can set ALLOW_PARALLEL_RUNS in your cron class to disallow multiple jobs of the type from running concurrently.

Comment: If runcrons wants to do the job and see it's locked, does it wait or ignore it?

Comment: @mohammad: According to [the source](https://github.com/Tivix/django-cron/blob/7fa5c2d2835520d8c920f3c103937ab292d9e545/django_cron/__init__.py), it'll raise LockFailedException and the error may be logged when silent=False, or otherwise silently ignored.